# Function return struct pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'd like to create an Octree data structure in C++.  I have a header file which is look like this:

```
class Octree
{
public:
    typedef struct node
    {
        int value;
        node *child[8];
    }node;

    Octree();
    ~Octree();

    int convert(int sorszam);
    void clear(struct node*);
    node* search(int dec,int oct);
};
```

And I'd like to write the search function in the .cpp file but I always got an error message. Here is the .cpp code:

```
node* Octree::search(int dec, int oct) {
//doing something here
return nullptr;
}
```

And the error message says:

> declaration is incompatible with "Octree::node *Octree::search(int dec, int oct)" (declared at line 19 of "c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\xxx\xxx\Octree.h")

I have no idea whats happening because the type of the two function is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing the return type in the cpp to `Octree::node*` instead of just `node*`. You also can drop the typedef, shouldn't need that in C++.

Comment: or move the typedef of struct node to outside the class

Comment: They can also get rid of the `typedef` as in C++ you do not need to decorate the name of a `struct` with `struct` when using it.

Comment: Is it possible, at the deffinition (cpp file) that you've cluttered your namespace with another deffinition for the token "node"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` for node is scoped to the class.  When you use

```
node* Octree::search(int dec, int oct)
```

outside of the class body the compiler does not know what node is as we are outside the scope of the class.  You need to qualify `node` with the class name like

```
Octree::node* Octree::search(int dec, int oct)
```

This allows the compiler to use the `node` from the class.

---

In `Octree` there is no reason to use a `typedef` on `node`.  Unlike C you do not have to use the `struct` keyword when using a `struct`.  You could have

```
class Octree
{
public:
    struct node
    {
        int value;
        node *child[8];
    };
    //...
};
```

and then you can just use `node` like you would with the `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea whats happening because the type of the two function is the same.

The types are *not* same. Inside the definition of `Octree`, you have defined a nested class `node`. Therefore, within the definition of `Octree`, the type name `node` refers to `Octree::node`. Outside the definition of `Octree` (where you have defined the member function) however, `node` does not refer to `Octree::node`. It refers to `::node` which may have been declared elsewhere.

> What am I doing wrong?

You're (accidentally) re-declaring the member function with a different return type than what it was declared to return. Simply use the fully qualified name to refer to the correct type:

```
Octree::node* Octree::search(int dec, int oct)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you haven't actually declared a type called `node`. You've declared a type called `Octree::node`.  Since the definition of the `Octree::search` function is outside of the class declaration, you need to use the fully-qualified name of the type:

```
Octree::node* Octree::search(int dec, int oct) {
...
```